# Scheduling database backup in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I am using SQL Server 2012. I want to schedule a daily database backup. Scheduling is possible using SQL Server Agent, but the problem with choosing Backup Type. I have read the backup types. But I couldn't understand what they are/mean.

Please tell me which type should I use. And post SQL script.

Comment: Install Ola Hallengren's maintenance solution or MinionBackup and schedule the backups using them (Ola's installs Agent jobs that you just have to schedule, MinionBackup is configured via table). This is a problem that's already solved for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you understand sql Scheduling  it's work for me. you can try this query

```
BACKUP DATABASE DBName
TO DISK = 'C:\DBName.BAK'
```

Comment: but this for full database backup. if i shedule the backup every time it ll take full backup.